# XQuery. Error: unknown function

Tags: function, xquery

I have an assignment:
Define the co-author graph G of the dblp-excerpt to be the undirected graph that has all authors as nodes, such that there is an edge between author a and author b in G if and only if a and b have written a publication together.

Define the distance between two authors a and b to be the length of the shortest path between a and b in G. Hence, authors that have published together have distance 1.

Moreover, if a and b have not published together but they have both published together with c, then the distance between a and b is two. Write an XQuery program that computes, for each pair of authors x and y 6= x the distance
between x and y using the following output format.

I wrote a code, but it doesn't work. I'm sure, it is very simple mistake, but I can't find it.

I have an error: Error:

> Stopped at C:/Users/Zhanna/Desktop/Test/test_3.xq, 28/44: [XPST0017]
>   Unknown function 'local:getAvailablePathSizes'.

It underlines the beginning of the list of arguments in line 28, which is:

```
return
local:getAvailablePathSizes($graph,$current,$target,$visitedList,$count+1)
```

I validate the query with the Saxon as well and it also give a msg like this:

> Error XPST0008: Unresolved reference to variable $count Static
>   error(s) in query

Help me, please, to fix it.

```
<ee>
let $graph:=(
  <graph>{
    for $a in distinct-values(//author)
    let $publications:=/dblp/*[author=$a]
    order by $a
    return
    <node name="{$a}">
    {
      let $co:=$publications/author[(.)!=$a] return
      for $distinctCo in distinct-values($co) return
      <edge from="{$a}" to="{$distinctCo}"/>
    }
    </node>
  }</graph>
 ) return

declare function local:getAvailablePathSizes
 ($graph, $start, $target, $visitedList, $count)
{
  let $cos:=$graph/node[@name=$start]/edge/@to return
  let $listOfDistances:=(
    for $current in $cos
    return
    if($current=$target) then $count+1 else
      if (empty(visitedList[.=$current])) then(
        let $visitedList:=insert-before(data($current), 0, $visitedList)
        return local:getAvailablePathSizes($graph,$current,$target,$visitedList,$count+1)
      ) else()
  )
  return $listOfDistances
};

<distances>
{
  for $node in $graph/node return
  for $to in $graph/node[@name!=$node/@name]
    let $dist:=min(local:getAvailablePathSizes($graph, $node/@name, $to/@name, null, 0))
    return
    if($dist>0) then(
      <distance
        author1="{$node/@name}"
        author2="{$to/@name}"
        distance="{$dist}"/>)
        else()
}
</distances>
</ee>
```

This is the XML file
http://www.filedropper.com/dblp

Comment: Please never retype error messages, but copy them. Are you really getting an error message with the _singular_  of the function name? There is no respective function call leading to such an error message. Please provide the full error message, including any line/column indications and/or stacktrace (if available). Furthermore, you're aware there is no `null` value in XQuery?

Comment: I use BaseX and it is impossible to copy there an error:( sorry:(
You are right, I mistyped and the error is: Unknown function "local:getAvailablePathSizes". It underlines the beginning of the list of arguments in line 28, which is:   return local:getAvailablePathSizes($graph,$current,$target,$visitedList,$count+1)

Comment: Open the Query Info pane (View->Query Info or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>). It shows a selectable error message. Please don't add information in the comments, edit your question instead (code is hardly readable in comments).

Comment: Now that's what a question should look like.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is, that you did omit curly braces around the XQuery code inside the `<ee>` element, so large parts of your code haven't been evaluated (but interpreted as text instead). This resulted in a barely helpful error message indicating the second problem: you must define functions in the so-called prolog before the "normal" XQuery statements (in the query body).

```
declare function local:getAvailablePathSizes
 ($graph, $start, $target, $visitedList, $count)
{
  let $cos:=$graph/node[@name=$start]/edge/@to return
  let $listOfDistances:=(
    for $current in $cos
    return
    if($current=$target) then $count+1 else
      if (empty(visitedList[.=$current])) then(
        let $visitedList:=insert-before(data($current), 0, $visitedList)
        return local:getAvailablePathSizes($graph,$current,$target,$visitedList,$count+1)
      ) else()
  )
  return $listOfDistances
};

<ee>{
let $graph:=(
  <graph>{
    for $a in distinct-values(//author)
    let $publications:=/dblp/*[author=$a]
    order by $a
    return
    <node name="{$a}">
    {
      let $co:=$publications/author[(.)!=$a] return
      for $distinctCo in distinct-values($co) return
      <edge from="{$a}" to="{$distinctCo}"/>
    }
    </node>
  }</graph>
 ) return

<distances>
{
  for $node in $graph/node return
  for $to in $graph/node[@name!=$node/@name]
    let $dist:=min(local:getAvailablePathSizes($graph, $node/@name, $to/@name, null, 0))
    return
    if($dist>0) then(
      <distance
        author1="{$node/@name}"
        author2="{$to/@name}"
        distance="{$dist}"/>)
        else()
}
</distances>
}
</ee>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help and sorry for inconveniences. I'm just a beginner:)

Comment: Your questions show own effort. This will usually be highly appreciated, don't worry!